# how to show widgets/ Custom layouts on lockscreen or on homescreen in Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appwidget, lockscreen, homescreen

I want to show my custom layout on homescreen or on lockscreen but i could not find any working example in Android 5.0 (Lollipop).

As suggested by @commonsware that this is not possible on 5.0 But how is this [Next Lock Screen app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.next&hl=en) is managing this on 5.0

I'd like to achieve something like [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.next&hl=en), Any direction or help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Android 5.0 got rid of app widgets on the lockscreen, so this is no longer supported. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData):

> The widgetCategory attribute declares whether your App Widget can be displayed on the home screen (home_screen), the lock screen (keyguard), or both. Only Android versions lower than 5.0 support lock-screen widgets. For Android 5.0 and higher, only home_screen is valid.

Comment: do you have any working example of homescreen widgets?

Comment: @ARK: Not for Android 5.0 and higher, as it is not supported. Lockscreen widgets was only supported for Android 4.2 through 4.4 ([~60% of the market and falling](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)). This project should work on those versions: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/TwoOrThreeDice

Comment: Thanks but i want to do something like this and its working on 5.0 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.next&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The [Adenda](http://www.adendamedia.com/) SDK lets you do just that. You simply design a fragment like you would in any other app and feed it into the SDK.

I'm affiliated with Adenda for full disclosure