# How to add task widget to lock screen on Android Phone?

Tags: android, flutter, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4.2

How can I add task app to the lock screen (not the home screen) on Android:

```
I have tried all suggestions on the internet nothing works 
https://github.com/ssaurel/LockScreenDevice 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526078/how-to-show-widgets-custom-layouts-on-lockscreen-or-on-homescreen-in-android-5
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/TwoOrThreeDice
```

If it is possible to do it with flutter or with Delphi 10.4 please show me a code to do this so I can add it to my app.

Comment: Please include in your question, which suggestions you have tried, including if you have tried this one: https://github.com/MyBuzzTechnologies/DelphiAndroidHomeScreenWidget

Comment: thank you but this add to home screen i need to add it to lockscreen

Comment: Then please follow my advice from my first comment, i.e. indicate what you have tried, but please include it in your question, and not in a comment.

Comment: It may also help to add a reference for whatever a lock screen task app actually is. Is there documentation for it in the Android developer reference? Are there examples (e.g. in Java or Kotlin) elsewhere?

Comment: i have added it to the question

Comment: This answer from one of your links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32526092/3164070 suggests that it's not even possible on Android 5 or greater. You may be better off describing *exactly* what you want to achieve and/or point to an app (preferably one on Play Store) that actually does what you want

Comment: i want to add a task app to screenlock